# Unwrap AES key on iOS

Tags: ios, encryption

We have a client-server architecture where the server returns AES keys wrapped with other AES keys using AES Key Wrap algorithm ([rfc 3394](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3394)) to the client. We need to implement a client on iOS that unwraps these keys.

I know absolutely nothing about iOS development (I'm responsible for the server and the web service API, so I specified AES Key Wrap assuming this wouldn't be an issue), and the client-side guys are telling me they're having a hard time implementing this.

So, how does one go about unwrapping an AES key on iOS? Is there a library that can do this?  i've found [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeyUnwrapSymmetric) which seems to be exactly what I need, but they claim it's unavailable.

Comment: I need this functionality in iOS (iPhone). If you're referring to the documentation I linked, then ok. I find it hard to tell from reading it whether it only applies to OS X or iOS as well. I saw some blurbs on the web that iOS has AES Wrapping, but I don't know if I understood it right, or whether it's exposed to the apps.

Comment: seems that iOS hasn't built-in AES wrapping as OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I am answering this question a bit loo late ... hopefully the answer will be useful for someone else.

Anyway, Apple provides these methods to wrap/unwrap a key:

- CCSymmetricKeyWrap
- CCSymmetricKeyUnwrap

They are located in `CommonCrypto/CommonSymmetricKeywrap.h` and are available in MacOS as well as iOS.

An example of use of these 2 methods would be as follows (notice that this code can not be used straight away in your own code because of the `XCTAssert's`):

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

// The size of the Key Encryptions Key has to be:
// kCCKeySizeAES128 (16), kCCKeySizeAES192 (24) or kCCKeySizeAES256 (32) bytes
u_int8_t kekBytes[kCCKeySizeAES128] = {
    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
    0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x10
};

// The size of the data to cipher has to be a multiple of 64 bits
u_int8_t plainBytes[2 * sizeof(u_int64_t)] = {
    0x10, 0x20, 0x30, 0x40, 0x50, 0x60, 0x70, 0x80,
    0x90, 0xA0, 0xB0, 0xC0, 0xD0, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0x11
};

// WRAP KEY

// The size of the ciphered data is equal to the size of the plain data
// + another 64 bits
size_t cipheredBytesSize = (sizeof(plainBytes) + sizeof(u_int64_t));
u_int8_t cipheredBytes[cipheredBytesSize];

CCCryptorStatus status = CCSymmetricKeyWrap(kCCWRAPAES,
                                            CCrfc3394_iv,
                                            CCrfc3394_ivLen,
                                            kekBytes,
                                            sizeof(kekBytes),
                                            plainBytes,
                                            sizeof(plainBytes),
                                            cipheredBytes,
                                            &cipheredBytesSize);
XCTAssertEqual(status, kCCSuccess);
XCTAssertEqual(cipheredBytesSize, sizeof(plainBytes) + sizeof(u_int64_t));

// UNWRAP KEY

size_t sizeDecipheredPlainData = sizeof(plainBytes);
u_int8_t decipheredPlainBytes[sizeDecipheredPlainData];

status = CCSymmetricKeyUnwrap(kCCWRAPAES,
                              CCrfc3394_iv,
                              CCrfc3394_ivLen,
                              kekBytes,
                              sizeof(kekBytes),
                              cipheredBytes,
                              cipheredBytesSize,
                              decipheredPlainBytes,
                              &sizeDecipheredPlainData);
XCTAssertEqual(status, kCCSuccess);
XCTAssertEqual(sizeDecipheredPlainData, sizeof(plainBytes));

XCTAssertEqual(memcmp(plainBytes, decipheredPlainBytes, sizeof(plainBytes)), 0);
```

Now, sometime ago I coded a library that conforms to [RFC 3394](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3394) and also to [RFC 5649](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5649). The latter, called AES Key Wrap with Padding, describes how to wrap/unwrap a key which size is not a multiple of 64 bits, in fact, it can be of any size. This library is located [here in GitHub](https://github.com/indisoluble/AesKeyWrap) and is also available in [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/pods/AesKeyWrap). But, to be honest, unless you have to wrap keys of any size, there is not much point on using it.

Nevertheless, below there is another example about how to use it:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

// The size of the Key Encryptions Key has to be:
// kCCKeySizeAES128 (16), kCCKeySizeAES192 (24) or kCCKeySizeAES256 (32) bytes
u_char kekBytes[kCCKeySizeAES128] = {
    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
    0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x10
};
NSData *keyEncryptionKey = [NSData dataWithBytes:kekBytes length:sizeof(kekBytes)];

// AES Key Wrap

// The size of the data to cipher has to be a multiple of 64 bits
u_char plainBytes[2 * sizeof(uint64_t)] = {
    0x10, 0x20, 0x30, 0x40, 0x50, 0x60, 0x70, 0x80,
    0x90, 0xA0, 0xB0, 0xC0, 0xD0, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0x11
};
NSData *expectedPlainData = [NSData dataWithBytes:plainBytes length:sizeof(plainBytes)];

NSData *cipheredData = [AKWAesKeyWrap cipheredDataByWrappingPlainData:expectedPlainData
                                                 withKeyEncryptionKey:keyEncryptionKey
                                                                error:nil];
NSData *plainData = [AKWAesKeyWrap plainDataByUnwrappingCipheredData:cipheredData
                                                withKeyEncryptionKey:keyEncryptionKey
                                                               error:nil];

XCTAssertEqualObjects(expectedPlainData, plainData);

// AES Key Wrap with Padding

// The plain data can be as small as 1 byte
u_char plainBytesWithPadding[1] = {0x10};
expectedPlainData = [NSData dataWithBytes:plainBytesWithPadding length:sizeof(plainBytesWithPadding)];

cipheredData = [AKWAesKeyWrap cipheredDataByWrappingWithPaddingPlainData:expectedPlainData
                                                   usingKeyEncryptionKey:keyEncryptionKey
                                                                   error:nil];
plainData = [AKWAesKeyWrap plainDataByUnwrappingWithPaddingCipheredData:cipheredData
                                                  usingKeyEncryptionKey:keyEncryptionKey
                                                                  error:nil];

XCTAssertEqualObjects(expectedPlainData, plainData);
```

Regards.